# xcode Code to install app

Tags: ios, xcode, installation

I want to achieve with the code, I write the program to install other applications to the phone, I found online said to be to app unzip and copy to the / var / mobile / Applications directory, I follow suitHowever, the installed program, you must restart the phone to display and install the application can not run

Comment: confused with this question, I am.

Comment: You want an app to install another app without the user going through the App Store?  Impossible without jail breaking.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have seen an application is the ipa, he can install other ipa to the phone, but must escape, I am not very clear, and I want to do a similar application, you can not publishappstroe, for learning, if you know how to do so, please tell me, thank you for your help

Comment: One thing you can do is you can open the appstore link for that application that needs to be installed.  So that the user can install the required app from app store.  If you want I can give the code for that..

Comment: You can install ipa via iTunes - ipa has to be developer-signed and device has to be listed as device used for development. If you want to be able to install ipa by yourself you need a jailbroken device. More on this: http://ipad-os.net/how-to-install-ipa-directly/

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding you correctly. It sounds like you just want to be able to test your app on a device. If you have paid for your Apple developer membership already, you can deploy your app to a device directly from Xcode.

Comment: i am so sorry, Perhaps my description of the problem is not correct, I just want the code to install an ipa applications to the iphone, rather than through the tool, my phone has been jailbroken,

Answer (score 0):

You can combine xcodebuild and xcrun commands to install and run your app.

The xcodebuild compile your project and create a .app file in DSTROOT that um point.

```
xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator8.4 -arch i386 install DSTROOT=~/MyApp
```

if you are using some pod file you have .xcworkspace instead .xcodeproj then add -workspace and -scheme at your xcodebuild.

```
xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator8.4 -arch i386 -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyApp install DSTROOT=~/MyApp
```

After created the .app file you can run into a Simulator device.

```
xcrun instruments -w "iPhone 6 (8.4 Simulator)"
xcrun simctl install booted ~/MyApp/Applications/MyApp.app
```

if you want to run in another Simulator device, try see all devices available.

```
xcrun instruments -s
```